# how can vba excel give a maximum value in a certain code

Tags: vba, excel

I have this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Vérification1_Click()

For i = 4 To 1295
    Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("C57").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteauxW").Cells(i, 6)
    Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("D57").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteauxW").Cells(i, 13)
    Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("E57").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteauxW").Cells(i, 8)

    If Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("H57") = "NG" Then
        MsgBox "NG on " & i
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
MsgBox "OK"

End Sub
```

How can I add an option that this code gives me the maximum value of the cell `Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("U57")` while it goes through the i values?

Comment: Not sure what you trying to achieve ? you are looping through 1291 rows, overwriting the values in "C57:E57" , while afterwards comparing value in "H57" to "NG". While in your post, you write you want to find `Max` in `Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("U57")` which is not in your code at all. Can you describe clearly what you want your code to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Vérification1_Click() 
maxu57=Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("U57")
maxrow=0
For i = 4 To 1295
  Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("C57").Value =     Sheets("Efforts poteauxW").Cells(i, 6) 
  Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("D57").Value =    Sheets("Efforts poteauxW").Cells(i, 13) 
  Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("E57").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteauxW").Cells(i, 8) 
  If maxu57<Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("U57").Value Then
    maxu57=Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("U57").Value
    maxrow=i
  End If
  If Sheets("PoteauxW").Range("H57") = "NG" Then 
    MsgBox "NG on " & i & " Max U57=" & maxu57 & " found for row="&i
    Exit Sub 
  End If 
Next i 
MsgBox "OK" & " Max U57=" & maxu57 & " found for row="&i
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i would like to know on which i was it the maximum

Comment: this one worked for me but i would like to add this option

Comment: Edited the answer to show for what row the max occured. But it is important that you understand the code and be able to ammend the same to your needs!